# Any ideas for this interesting problem?

Tags: analysis, problems

[image]

Any ideas for this interesting problem?

Answer (score 6):

The black king threatens to escape via e4, so

```
8/2Q5/8/3k2K1/8/8/4NP2/8 w - - 3 13

1. f3 Ke6 {(forced)}
2. Nf4#
```

(sidenote: I'm really divided into putting the solution in a 'spoiler' block with `>!` (as is customary on Puzzles.SE)

> like this

and the current way, with a diagram to allow playback. It would be very nice if we could put the diagram *inside* the spoiler.)